# HTML entities when editing top answers on careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, html-entities

When editing the "Top Answers" section on a careers profile, the answer titles have raw HTML entities:

[image: "Difference between nohup, disown, and &" and "best way to search my shell&#39s history"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out shortly.  This was caused when switching from APIv1 to APIv2.